# Checkboxes in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, checkbox

What I'm wanting to do is add checkboxes and have a title for each checkbox and have if certain boxes are checked then it displays certain texts like

if box 1, box 2, box 4, and box 5 are selected then displays text1

if box 1 is selected then displays text2

if box 1, box 3, and box 4 are selected then displays text3

Something like that.  Help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the UI use a UiTableViewController with two images one for unchecked and the other for the checked state. Those images are assigned to the UITableViewCell's imageView property.

For checking state, I would store all values into one int field and make a corresponding typedef enum so that i could use a bitwise & to check to see if a value or combination of values is selected.

I could post some code later if needed.

Comment: Personally, that is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UISwitch controls for a simple on/off control, and UILabel controls for text. You could have a single UILabel whose text changes, or multiple ones and mark them hidden depending on which switches are on.